# CASE WHEN using value from another column returns value of initial column

Tags: sql-server-2012, case-when

I have what I hope is a simple issue. I am trying to establish a value of `Field1` when `Field2` equals a certain conditions.

For example

```
CASE 
   WHEN Column1 IN ('118', '119') 
      THEN Column2 = 0 
      ELSE Column2 
END AS Column2
```

But for whatever reason I cannot nail this down. Can someone assist?

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns one, atomic value - it's not like in other programming languages, and it cannot be used for "flow control" (selectively running one piece of code over another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your `SELECT`:

```
CASE WHEN Column1 IN ('118','119') THEN 0 ELSE Column2 END AS Column2
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess it was really that simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No need to have the equal sign.

```
CASE WHEN Column1 IN ('118','119') THEN 0 ELSE Column2 END AS Column2
```